# Адаптивная верстка шапки сайта с помощью flexbox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, адаптивная-верстка

Искал в интернете -[Адаптивная верстка шапки сайта](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20flex&newwindow=1&sxsrf=APq-WBuucHsYYlou2Vxjti6R0XHdE569Mg%3A1648447691969&source=hp&ei=y1BBYqufOa6prgSow4mYDg&iflsig=AHkkrS4AAAAAYkFe2wPt-4xsebMIW1mbSAogXN4VMh-m&ved=0ahUKEwjrsO-Ykuj2AhWulIsKHahhAuMQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20flex&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgQIIxAnOgYIABAWEB5QAFjFM2CkOGgAcAB4AYABuw6IAaw-kgEHMS42LjgtNJgBAKABAqABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz). Но везде, где бы не смотрел - приводятся примеры с **`justify-content: space-between`**. Подскажите, как сверстать адаптивную шапку **с процентными margin-ами** (не подходящую под кальку флексбокса) относительно ширины всей шапки между элементами шапки и как заверстать адаптивность (к примеру шапка сайта состоит из 4-х блоков - логотипа, первого меню, второго меню и кнопок). Только расстояния не должны быть удобными - типа 25%, 50%, 75%, а должны быть наподобие - 27%, 30%, 43%, 59%, 57% (это просто примеры, а в том примере кода, который приведете вы могут быть любые неудобные расстояния- необязательно эти). Пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

самая первая строка.

1-й блок - Ваш регион Калининградская область, 2-й блок - меню, 3-й блок - Зарегистрируйся и получи подарок, 4-й блок - Войти на сайт. Или можно любую страницу с [Примеров шапки сайта](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0%20%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%204-%D1%85%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&newwindow=1&sxsrf=APq-WBshDKK1SuQk1deiiGHARjnXntVhOA:1648455414050&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqqIf7ruj2AhXpoosKHc11CtEQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1366&bih=628&dpr=1) (но так чтобы блоков было бы хотя бы 3 и расстояния между ними были неудобными (см. выше)) Если нужен гамбургер, то уменьшите ширину блоков - гамбургер делать не надо (в таком случае 3-й блок просто Регистрация).

Comment: Можете привести пример или нарисовать схематичный макет, что вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 0):

Пример адаптива

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}
.header-logo {
    flex: 0 1 25%;
}
.header-secondblock {
    flex: 0 1 20%;
    margin-left: 30%;
}
.header-lastblock {
    flex: 0 1 10%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
.btn {
}

.my-ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Test header</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header-logo">
            Логотип
        </div>
        <div class="header-secondblock">
            <ul class="my-ul">
                <li>First item</li>
                <li>Second item</li>
                <li>Third item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="header-lastblock">
            <a href="" class="btn">First btn</a>
            <a href="" class="btn">Second btn</a>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Если кто-то знает, то также подскажите как без % задать адаптив.